# how to draw dotted line vertical line at 0 postiion in highChart

Tags: highcharts, chart.js

I want the dotted line at 0 position which is on x axis.I have tried the below changes but its applying to the bar margin.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },

    legend: {
        symbolWidth: 80
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            color: '#000000'
        },
        value:0,
         dashStyle: 'Dot',
         padding:10
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, -6, 2, 3, 5, 6],
      
    }, {
        data: [2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a dotted line on an axis by using the [`plotLines`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines). Like this:

```
yAxis: {
  plotLines: [{
    color: '#FF0000',
    value: 0,
      dashStyle: 'dot',
  width: 5
  }]
},
```

Here added to the yAxis to create a vertical line:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },

  legend: {
    symbolWidth: 80
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      color: '#000000',
    }

  },
  yAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
    color: '#FF0000',
      value: 0,
      dashStyle: 'dot',
      width: 5
    }]
  },

  series: [{
    data: [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, -6, 2, 3, 5, 6],

  }, {
    data: [2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],

  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have tried this one in my demo but could not get the dotted line.

Comment: You can click run on the code snippet I have pasted and you can see it work. If you need further help, you need to clarify what exactly is the problem, what you are doing and in what environment.